# How do I restrict the domain of a graph?

Tags: r

I'm plotting multiple graphs and I want the domain of the base plot between -1 and 1 to be non existent as that's where the restricted graphs are:

```
x1 = seq(-1,0,0.01)
x2 = seq(0, 1, 0.01)
base = seq(-4, 4, 0.01)
y1 = function(x) {(1+x)^3}
y2 = function(x) {(1-x)^2}
plot(base, 0*base, xlab="x", ylab="y")
points(x1, y1(x1))
points(x2, y2(x2))
```

Currently there's a line running through where the x1 and x2 are. I'd like it to only run between `-4` and `1`, and `1` and `4`. I've tried plotting the base twice but then things just won't be in the base plot due to the restriction. I'd be able to use `xlim` or `ylim` for the edges but this restriction is between `-1` and `1` and I have no idea.

Comment: What do you mean you want the restriction in the middle of the graph?

Comment: @AmandaR. sorry edited for clarity. Restriction of the base plot to be between -1 and 1, which is where my `y1` and `y2` plots are

Comment: I think you are looking for the `xlim` parameter to `plot`

Comment: @G5W if i use `xlim` it would only work for `-4` to `1`, or `1` to `4`, but not both as the initial plot would just cut off the other half.

Comment: Try `is.na(base) <- -1 <= base & base <= 1` before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing what you want is to have the relevant part of `base` as `NA` and those points will not be plotted.

This is the data and functions as in the question.

```
x1 <- seq(-1, 0, 0.01)
x2 <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
base <- seq(-4, 4, 0.01)
y1 <- function(x) {(1 + x)^3}
y2 <- function(x) {(1 - x)^2}
```

Now use function `is.na<-` to make everything in `base` between `-1` and `1` equal to `NA`.

```
is.na(base) <- -1 <= base & base <= 1
```

And run the graphics commands unchanged.

```
plot(base, 0*base, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
points(x1, y1(x1))
points(x2, y2(x2))
```

[image]